# Should I test an enum?

Tags: java, testing, enums

If you have a simple ENUM with values only. Getters are available.

- Should a unit tests be written for this ENUM?
- Should a test cover all type names?

Any advise?

```
// ENUM with constructor and methods.
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY(3.303e+23, 2.4397e6),
    VENUS(4.869e+24, 6.0518e6),
    EARTH(5.976e+24, 6.37814e6),
    MARS(6.421e+23, 3.3972e6),
    JUPITER(1.9e+27, 7.1492e7),
    SATURN(5.688e+26, 6.0268e7),
    URANUS(8.686e+25, 2.5559e7),
    NEPTUNE(1.024e+26, 2.4746e7);

    // Members
    private final double mass; // in kilograms
    private final double radius; // in meters

    // Constructor
    Planet(double mass, double radius) {
        this.mass = mass;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    // Accessors
    public double getMass() {
        return mass;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: What "unit" would you test ? that the getters work ?

Comment: Testing an enum doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: Don't blindly follow rules like "there must be a unit test for every line of code". Think about what you are doing is actually of any value or not. Do you think it would make sense to write a unit test for this enum? What would be the purpose of the test? What problem would such a test solve?

Comment: *UnitTest*s test **behavior**. Your enum is only *data* so no unit test is needed.

Comment: If I was **forced** to write a test for this `enum` I would probably just check that that none of the masses/radii were zero or negative. I may check that they are in a sane range too but not much more.

Comment: Typical data-like enums like yours shouldn't be tested, except maybe for simple sanity checks as already mentioned. But sometimes enums _can_ also be fully fletched classes with behavior, in which case the should be tested the same way as any other class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a simple yes-or-no-question but depends very much on the context.

If this enum is a critical part of a huge project with a lot of programmers and weak communication structures and you want to assure that no one has accidentally changed this critical part, a reasonable junit test could look like this:

```
public class PlanetTest {
    private final static int NUM_PLANETS = 8;

    @Test
    public void testIntegrity() {
        assertEquals(NUM_PLANETS, Planet.values().length);

        for (Planet planet : Planet.values()) {
            assertTrue("Wierd: Mass in kg is less than radius in m", 
                planet.getMass() > planet.getRadius());
            }
        }
    }
```

Writing this test case (with the help of an IDE) took even less time than reading your question and you are assured that no planet is missing or has corrupted values (once and for every regression test run).

Another benefit of writing test code (in test-driven development) is that the programmer is *forced to think about implementation issues before* he/she writes the actual code. This may improve the microdesign of code. Even in this trivial example I could think of issues to think about before implementing:

- Should there be a method which returns radius in miles or km?
- Should there be a method which returns mass in tons?
- Should for some legacy reasons Pluto be considered as a planet?
- ....

Comment: This is a good answer for this specific test.  The author alluded to not testing.  I would suggest that if there are no methods in the enum except a constructor, it would be optional to test.  One then can only test the actual values = some strings in the test, which is foolish.